# Testing OpenTok flash on multiple browsers, one browser publishes video fine but the other shows a black screen

Tags: javascript, tokbox, opentok

I am getting a blank screen when connecting to an existing session and 
trying to publish on that.The flash 'allow'/'deny' screen appears but 
after pressing allow, there is only a black screen with settings icon in 
the publisher div. what can be the issue? A different browser instance is open as well and that publishes fine.

Here is the log details if you need:

```
Connected [DEBUG] opentok: OpenTok JavaScript library v1.1.4  
[DEBUG] opentok: Release notes: http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/js/documentation/overview/releaseNotes.html  
[DEBUG] opentok: Known issues: http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/js/documentation/overview/releaseNotes.html#knownIssues  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.setLogLevel(4)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.checkSystemRequirements()  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.initSession(...sessionId...)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(sessionConnected)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(sessionDisconnected)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(connectionCreated)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(connectionDestroyed)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(streamCreated)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.addEventListener(streamDestroyed)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.connect(22055202)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.checkSystemRequirements()  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.sessionConnected: ...sessionId... - 7626c1323c18263598e3f7661151a79a97a43bda  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(sessionConnected)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.streamCreated  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(streamCreated)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.subscribe(1695484121)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(loaded)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.streamPropertyChangedHandler  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(streamPropertyChanged)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.initPublisher(opentok_publisher)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.publish([object Object]):undefined  
[DEBUG] opentok: Pending: publishToSession(...sessionId...,7626c1323c18263598e3f7661151a79a97a43bda,T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yMjA1NTIwMiZzaWc9ZmEyNjkxYzA0OGY1MTA3ZDFjZDVmYWQ2Yjc5MzVkNjdiMDUyMDNjMzpzZX) on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.resize  
[DEBUG] opentok: Component loaded: publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: callFlash: publishToSession(...sessionId... ,7626c1323c18263598e3f7661151a79a97a43bda,T1==lPS0xMzc1OTg2NzE5JnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJmNvbm5lY3Rpb25fZGF0YT11c2VybmFtZSUzRG9uZSUyQ3VzZXJMZXZlbCUzRDE=,22055202) on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(loaded)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessDialogOpened  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(accessDialogOpened)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.resize  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessDialogClosed  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(accessDialogClosed)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceAccessHandler: accessAllowed  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(accessAllowed)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.micGainChangedHandler:50  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(microphoneGainChanged)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.echoCancellationModeChangedHandler  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(echoCancellationModeChanged)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.streamCreated  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(streamCreated)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.deviceInactiveHandler  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(deviceInactive)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.streamPropertyChangedHandler  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(streamPropertyChanged)  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.streamPropertyChangedHandler  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(streamPropertyChanged)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.disconnect()  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.sessionDisconnected(clientDisconnected)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.disconnectComponents() - disconnecting publishers and subscribers  
[DEBUG] opentok: Pending: unpublishFromSession(...sessionId...) on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: callFlash: unpublishFromSession(...sessionId...) on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.cleanupConnection() - removing controller  
[DEBUG] opentok: TB.dispatchEvent(sessionDisconnected)  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.cleanup()  
[DEBUG] opentok: Pending: cleanupView() on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: callFlash: cleanupView() on component publisher_1  
[DEBUG] opentok: Session.unsubscribe(subscriber_1695484121_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hope it might help someone. In the older versions of flash, if one browser has access of the webcam, the other browsers is not able to get access, hence a black screen on one browser and video on the other.

Updating flash to the latest version seems to have fixed my problem.